# jquery $.post data to popup window from a popup window

Tags: php, jquery, post

I'm trying to post data to a new window (using window.open) from a popup that was opened with the window.open method. What I'm trying to do is pass the selected option value to the newly opened window and load data using $_POST.

Here's what I tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '.openForm', function()
{
    var select = $(this).data('select'),
        val    = $('#'+ select).val();

    $.post('/path/to/page.php', {id: val}, function(res)
    {
        window.open('/path/to/page.php');
    });
});
```

and currently page.php has a var_dump of $_POST which returns empty. It also opens the page in a new tab instead of a new window - I think this is to do with giving the open windows unique names?

I'm not sure how to get it so $.post works with posting to the same page and opening it with the sent data - any links or solutions you know of that could work?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your script like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '.openForm', function()
{
    var select = $(this).data('select'),
        val    = $('#'+ select).val();


    $.post('/path/to/page.php', {id: val}, function(res)
    {
        console.log(res);

        var myWindow = window.open("", "MyWindow", "width=600,height=600");
        myWindow.document.write(res);
        //window.open('test_json.php',1,'width=600, height=600');
    });
});

</script>
```

1) var_dump of $_POST returns empty. Because your both request `$.post('/path/to/page.php')` and `window.open('/path/to/page.php');` will be different.  1st treated as post and after completion of it `window.open('/path/to/page.php');` will be arise which will be `get` request.

2) To open window on same not in new tab you have to pass its width and height as 3rd parameter in `window.open()` method.